# what does Num*Obj means in Spock

Tags: spock

Let's say `deleteInvocation=1, notDeletedInvocation=2`

Does that mean I will have 3 records in the Post array before entering?

`3 * postConverter.apply(Post, null) >> PostPayload`

```
@Unroll
def "Verify PostCoreImpl.findById return  Post when includeRemoved: [#includeRemoved]"() {
    setup:
    def PostId = UUID.randomUUID()
    def Post = Mock(Post)
    def PostPayload = Mock(PostPayload)

    when:
    def actual = underTest.findPostById(PostId, includeRemoved, false, false)

    then:
    deleteInvocation * mockPostDataManager.findByIdincludeRemoved(PostId) >> Post
    notDeletedInvocation * mockPostDataManager.findById(PostId) >> Post
    3 * postConverter.apply(Post, null) >> PostPayload
    actual == PostPayload

    where:
    deleteInvocation | notDeletedInvocation | includeRemoved
    1                | 0                    | true
    0                | 1                    | false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would advise against using variable names starting with capital letters, especially if these variables are identical with actual class names(!). For example, I would change

```groovy
def PostId = UUID.randomUUID()
def Post = Mock(Post)
def PostPayload = Mock(PostPayload)
```

to

```groovy
def postId = UUID.randomUUID()
def post = Mock(Post)
def postPayload = Mock(PostPayload)
```

and update all places where these variables are used.

---

As for your question, the notation `integerNumber * methodCall(...)` on a mock or spy object means that you want to verify that `methodCall(...)` was called exactly `integerNumber` times during your test (interaction checking).

Please consult the [Spock manual chapter "Interactions"](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/interaction_based_testing.html#_interactions) for further information.

The notation `integerNumber * methodCall(...) >> stubResult` means that you combine interactions with stubbing, i.e. specify two things at once with a mock or spy object.

Please consult the [Spock manual chapter "Combining Mocking and Stubbing"](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/interaction_based_testing.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) for further information.

Comment: Does " >>" mean `assign` ? for example  methodCall will return a new obj, in this case two new createdly objects will be added into stubResult?

Comment: No, it means "return". You are specifying which result your mock should return (other than the default null or zero) when specific methods are being called. This is called stubbing. Why don't you just read the Spock manual, it is really good and has lots of simple examples. (SO is not a teaching site, we are mainly trying to solve technical problems here.) Would you mind accepting + upvoting my answer if you think it was helpful? Thank you.